# CNAME DKIM "Hosting"

Tags: dns, cname, dkim

I've ran into an issue where one of our domains is hosted with a company that only allows 1024 bit DKIM public keys, however the server that sends out emails has the DKIM public keys set and enforced to 2048 bit.

I'm looking to "host" the 2048 bit DKIM key on a different domain and link it across to the main domain with a CNAME record.

Similar to how Mailchimp does it with their DKIM keys, where by you setup the record:

`CNAME` `k1._domainkey` `dkim.mcsv.net`

For reference if you lookup the DNS records for that mailchimp server the only one available is:

`dkim.mcsv.net. 21593 IN TXT "k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDbNrX2cY/GUKIFx2G/1I00ftdAj713WP9AQ1xir85i89sA2guU0ta4UX1Xzm06XIU6iBP41VwmPwBGRNofhBVR+e6WHUoNyIR4Bn84LVcfZE20rmDeXQblIupNWBqLXM1Q+VieI/eZu/7k9/vOkLSaQQdml4Cv8lb3PcnluMVIhQIDAQAB;"`

I'm wanting to copy this setup for a so I can host the DKIM key on something like `hosteddkim.mywebsite.com`

The server that sends out the emails wanted the DKIM key to look like:

`TXT` `default._domainkey` `v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGLONGLONGSTRINGHERE`

The domain that I want to host the DKIM key on, I tried to setup like:

`TXT` `default._domainkey.hosteddkim` `v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGLONGLONGSTRINGHERE`

I then set the following up on the domain where I am limited to a 1024 bit DKIM key:

`CNAME` `default._domainkey` `hosteddkim.mywebsite.com`

However it doesn't detect that the DKIM key for some reason... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The TXT record you create is for `default._domainkey.hosteddkim.mywebsite.com`, so you need to point the the CNAME record to this hostname, not to `hosteddkim.mywebsite.com`.

Comment: It unfortunately made no difference. Where does it detect the "default" or in Mailchimps case, the "k1"?

Comment: Would you tell us the domain name to check for the CNAME and TXT records. May be the server cached the previous record and you need to wait for the TTL to expire.